# google.script.run works in one sheet, won't work in another

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script, google-sheets, modal-dialog

I have a large Google Sheets project and I'm trying to add to it the functionality to open a modal dialog and send info back to the sheet from it. The bizarre issue I'm having is that in my main project it doesn't work, but the exact same code in a new project works just fine.

In both cases, for now for testing, I'm calling the function that opens the dialog from a Macro:

```
function TestMacro() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  spreadsheet.getRange('A1').activate();

  var brokenParts = ["4wfecS", "5few4s", "f5aews"];
  OpenAddCatalog(brokenParts);
};
```

Then there is the code in the Code.gs file:

```
// this function opens the dialog for adding new parts to the catalog
function OpenAddCatalog(brokenParts){
  var templ = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('AddCatalog');
  templ.firstName = "test";
  templ.partData = brokenParts;
  var message = templ.evaluate().getContent();
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(message).setWidth(810).setHeight(150),"Add Parts To Catalog");
}

// this is the function called from the script in the html file
function AddToCatalog(inp){
  return "from MasterSheet" + inp;   // this is just to test if I'm getting a return from this function
}
```

Then this is the HTML file (ignore that other functionality here is incomplete, I'm still working on it. The main point is that what does work works in my test spreadsheet, and doesn't in my main spreadsheet):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
    <script>

      function SubmitCatalog(idNum)
      {
        document.getElementById("displayCatalog").innerHTML = "<span style=\"font-weight: bold\" >" + idNum + "</span>";
        google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(Test).AddToCatalog(idNum);
      }

      function Test(ret){
        document.getElementById("displayCatalog2").innerHTML = "<span style=\"font-weight: bold\" >" + ret + "</span>";
      }

    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="AddCatalog" >
      <?= firstName ?>
    <table style="height: 54px; width: 700px;" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="1"><colgroup><col width="100" /><col width="100" /><col width="500" /><col width="100" /></colgroup>
      <tbody>
        <tr bgcolor="#434343">
          <td style="text-align: left;"><span style="color: #ffffff;">&nbsp;Part #</span></td>
          <td style="text-align: left;"><span style="color: #ffffff;">&nbsp;MFG</span></td>
          <td style="text-align: left;"><span style="color: #ffffff;">&nbsp;Description</span></td>
          <td style="text-align: left;"><span style="color: #ffffff;">&nbsp;Submit</span></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td style="text-align: left;"><input id="partNoCat" size="10" type="text" /></td>
          <td style="text-align: left;"><input id="mfg" size="5" type="text" /></td>
          <td style="text-align: left;"><input id="desc" size="40" type="text" /></td>
          <td style="text-align: left;"><input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="SubmitCatalog(555)"/></td>
        </tr>
        <? for(var i = 0; i < (partData.length); i++) { ?>
          <tr >
            <td style="text-align: left;"><input id="partNoCat" size="10" type="text" /></td>
            <td style="text-align: left;"><input id="mfg" size="5" type="text" /></td>
            <td style="text-align: left;"><input id="desc" size="60" type="text" /></td>
            <td style="text-align: left;"><input id="Submit" type="button" value="Submit" onclick="SubmitCatalog()"/></td>
            <script>
              document.getElementById("partNoCat").id = "partNoCat" + <?= i ?>;
              document.getElementById("partNoCat").value = <?= partData[i] ?>;
              document.getElementById("mfg").id = "mfg" + <?= i ?>;
              document.getElementById("desc").id = "desc" + <?= i ?>;
              document.getElementById("Submit").setAttribute("onclick", <?= "SubmitCatalog(" + i + ")" ?>);
            </script>
          </tr>
        <? } ?>
      </tbody>
    </table>
      
    <table style="height: 54px; width: 800px;" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="1"><colgroup><col width="100" /><col width="350" /><col width="350" /></colgroup>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td style="text-align: left;"><input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="SubmitCatalog()"/></td>
          <td style="text-align: left;"><div id="displayCatalog" >disp here</div></td>
          <td style="text-align: left;"><div id="displayCatalog2" >disp2 here</div></td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
    </div>

  </body>
</html>
```

Hope someone can shed some light on this because I am STUMPED.

Comment: Just to add a little more info that perhaps is relevant, I also can not get a toast working in my main Google Sheet, but the exact same code works in a test file as well.

I can get a toast to popup when I run it from a macro, but not from an onSelectionChange(e).

Comment: What have you done to debug it?

Comment: @Cooper what could I do to debug it? I’m at a loss. Again, my code works just fine in a test spreadsheet, but doesn’t work in my main project spreadsheet.

Comment: I used Chrome Developer tools to debug webapps and dialogs.

Comment: And I alsoo required an html validator in this case

Answer (score 0):

This works for me including sending idNum to AddToCatalog() in server code:

gs:

```
function TestMacro() {
  var brokenParts = ["4wfecS", "5few4s", "f5aews"];
  OpenAddCatalog(brokenParts);
}

function OpenAddCatalog(brokenParts){
  var templ = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('ah5');
  templ.firstName = "test";
  templ.partData = brokenParts;
  var message = templ.evaluate().getContent();
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(message).setWidth(1200).setHeight(150),"Add Parts To Catalog");
}

function AddToCatalog(inp){
  Logger.log("Server AddToCatalog")
  Logger.log(inp)
}
```

html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <base target="_top">
    <script>
      function SubmitCatalog(idNum){
        console.log(idNum);
        document.getElementById("displayCatalog").innerHTML = "<span style=\"font-weight: bold\" >" + idNum + "</span>";
        google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(Test).AddToCatalog(idNum);
      }

      function Test(ret){
        document.getElementById("displayCatalog2").innerHTML = "<span style=\"font-weight: bold\" >" + ret + "</span>";
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="AddCatalog" >
      <?= firstName ?>
    <table>
        <tr bgcolor="#434343">
          <td style="text-align: left;"><span style="color: #ffffff;">&nbsp;Part #</span></td>
          <td style="text-align: left;"><span style="color: #ffffff;">&nbsp;MFG</span></td>
          <td style="text-align: left;"><span style="color: #ffffff;">&nbsp;Description</span></td>
          <td style="text-align: left;"><span style="color: #ffffff;">&nbsp;Submit</span></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td style="text-align: left;"><input id="partNoCat" size="10" type="text" /></td>
          <td style="text-align: left;"><input id="mfg" size="5" type="text" /></td>
          <td style="text-align: left;"><input id="desc" size="40" type="text" /></td>
          <td style="text-align: left;"><input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="SubmitCatalog(555)"/></td>
        </tr>
        <? for(var i = 0; i < (partData.length); i++) { ?>
          <tr >
            <td style="text-align: left;"><input id="partNoCat" size="10" type="text" /></td>
            <td style="text-align: left;"><input id="mfg" size="5" type="text" /></td>
            <td style="text-align: left;"><input id="desc" size="60" type="text" /></td>
            <td style="text-align: left;"><input id="S-<?= i ?>" type="button" value="Submit" onclick="SubmitCatalog()"/></td>
            <script>
              document.getElementById("partNoCat").id = "partNoCat" + <?= i ?>;
              document.getElementById("partNoCat").value = <?= partData[i] ?>;
              document.getElementById("mfg").id = "mfg" + <?= i ?>;
              document.getElementById("desc").id = "desc" + <?= i ?>;
              document.getElementById("S-<?= i ?>").setAttribute("onclick","SubmitCatalog("  + <?= i ?> + ")");
            </script>
          </tr>
        <? } ?>
    </table>
      
    <table style="height: 54px; width: 800px;" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="1"><colgroup><col width="100" /><col width="350" /><col width="350" /></colgroup>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td style="text-align: left;"><input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="SubmitCatalog(111)"/></td>
          <td style="text-align: left;"><div id="displayCatalog" >disp here</div></td>
          <td style="text-align: left;"><div id="displayCatalog2" >disp2 here</div></td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
    </div>

  </body>
</html>
```